# Minecraft Links Open Internet Explorer, Not Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, minecraft

When I click on a link in minecraft, and open the link it opens in internet explorer, even though I think chrome is my default browser. How can I fix this?

Comment: 1. Make sure Chrome is your default browser.

Comment: "Make google chrome your default browser" when I click a Window opens asking me how would you like to open this kind of link? And when I click chrome nothing happens. @Xavierjazz

Comment: I don't understand. What does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the control panel> default programs. You should be able to set it there. If not, the game may be hard-wired to use IE.

Comment: It's not hardwired, and this worked. Thank you.